# Adjective meaning stubborn or willfully ignorant, to one's detriment

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm a writing a letter that goes:

> Your correspondent John Smith is correct that exercise has its costs, both in terms of cost of food and cost of equipment and gym memberships. However, to argue that it's therefore not worthwhile, is pig-in-the-mud [stubborn].

**stupid** would be a pretty good word, but it's rude and alienates the subject.

**stubborn** doesn't cover that it's an unintelligent action.

It's not **ignorant** because the information is available.

Comment: ... *is to [ignore/discount] its benefits which far outweigh the costs.*  But what does the cost of food have to do with exercise? And who says you need a gym membership or expensive equipment in order to exercise?

Comment: @Jim - The guy was arguing that the cost of protein powder, fresh fruit etc, is too much. Regarding benefits outweighing the costs, that's the next sentence. I'm looking for an adjective here.

Comment: Protein powder and fresh fruit have nothing to do with exercise.  I think you need a new noun.

Comment: How about [*specious*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specious)? Although that would be rude and alienating as well.

Comment: If it were I, I would stick with something less abrasive, especially if the interlocutor is a potential customer. The strongest word I might use here is *wrong*: to argue that is wrong. As @Jim suggested, *specious* is better. You are modifying *argument* or *argue*: an argument is not *stubborn* or *ignorant*. You can say that an argument is *stupid* (though that really is not correct), but again, don't do that if you want to persuade the person to exercise etc. ;-)

Comment: Another related word is **foolhardy**.

Comment: I'd say ignore-ant, but society's been willfully ignoring the fact that the popular definition of the word does not match a literal definition ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'bloody-minded'--describes someone who makes things difficult for others and opposes their views for no good reason. (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: That's a good one, thank you. Question is, would it be published in a newspaper?

Comment: This sense is chiefly British.

Comment: Everything 'bloody' is British.

Answer (score 2):

Obstinate - perversely adhering to an opinion, purpose, or course in spite of reason, arguments, or persuasion .

Comment: Hello, Mikish. This looks like a quote, which is good. But if it is, it needs attributing.

Answer (score 1):

***Ignorant*** is used in this sense also for someone who intentionally ignores. You can consider ***ignoramus*** as a noun.

> The word ignorant is an adjective describing a person in the state of being unaware and is **often used as an insult to describe individuals who deliberately ignore or disregard important information or facts.** Ignoramus is commonly used in the US, the UK, and Ireland as a term for someone who is willfully ignorant. Ignorance is distinguished from stupidity, although both can lead to "unwise" acts.
>
> <sup>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignorance</sup>

Another term that might fit is ***willful***, which can be used for someone who is stubbornly ignorant even he or she is aware of the consequences.

> Having or showing a stubborn and determined intention to do as one wants, regardless of the consequences or effects
>
> <sup>http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/willful</sup>

There are synonyms of willful like *headstrong* and *self-willed* but they are closer to stubbornness than ignorance. There seems to be a fine line between stubbornness and ignorance.

***Note:*** The blank in your example is better filled with a noun. So in this case, *ignorance* or *willfulness* would fit.

> *wilfullness (n)* a steadfast adherence to an opinion, purpose, or course of action in spite of reason, arguments, or persuasion
>
> *her unceasing willfulness eventually wore down her critics and opponents*
>
> <sup>http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/willfulness</sup>

---

Alright, if you want a strong word but not as derogatory as *stupid*, you can consider *bullheaded* for the person, and *bullheadedness* for the blank in your example.

> *bullheaded (adj)* not willing to change an opinion, plan, etc. : very stubborn in a foolish or annoying way

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bullheadedness

Comment: Someone is being ignorant of the answer :)

Comment: In much of the USA, you'd be far more likely to hear [muleheaded](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/muleheaded) than bullheaded, and the former would be more readily understood.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the adjective *adamant*.

> Refusing to be persuaded or to change one's mind (Google dictionary); impervious to pleas, appeals, or reason; stubbornly unyielding. [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adamant)

Of course, it doesn't show the stupidity, but it certainly shows a willfully ignorant nature, and justifies the purpose.

Comment: There's lots of spelling mistakes in this answer, do you mind fixing them?

Comment: @dwjohnston - For you, anything. {sarc} Really, this person went to the effort of trying to help you (I presume). Where is the love?

Answer (score 0):

This word is probably more in use in the [USA Southern Midlands dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_American_English#Midland_and_Highland), but I'd say [ornery](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ornery) is just about the perfect word for this concept. For instance, for someone who is arguing just because they like to argue, or because they started and don't want to stop, you could say they are "just being ornery".

The only thing that kind of spoils it is that this term is often used half-affectionately, so you'd have to change the tone of your sentence a bit. That might be for the best though. No need to be more confrontational than you have to be.

Answer (score 0):

> To argue that it's therefore not worthwhile would be **imprudent**.

im·pru·dent, adjective \ -dənt\

> not wise or sensible; not prudent; lacking discretion, wisdom, or good judgment  -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imprudent)

Calling someone's decision imprudent is a nice way of saying *that's a stupidly bad idea*.